# Justification for extending Gibbs entropy to non-equilibrium states

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy

I am taking a course in statistical mechanics and have seen the Gibbs, Boltzmann and Clausius formulations for entropy in equilibrium thermodynamic states. And I have seen that it can be shown that these are all equivalent.

The Gibbs formulation is given by:

$$S_G = -k_B \sum p_i log(p_i)$$,

where the sum is over all the accessible microstates to the system. In the equilibrium case, we assume that all of these microstates are equally probable, however, the appeal of the Gibbs formulation, from what I have read, is that it can be extended to non-equilibrium states, at which point the Boltzmann definition is no longer valid. In such non-equilibrium states we allow for the possibility that the $p_i$ terms are different.

My question is, what motivates the validity of this extension? I've seen parallels to Shannon entropy in information theory but I was hoping for a more rigorous mathematical argument for why it's reasonable to define entropy outside of a well-defined thermodynamic state in this way.

Comment: That the $p_i$'s are different does not correspond to a non-equilibrium condition. Again, an example is the canonical ensemble.

Comment: Hi again,
Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the canonical ensemble but I was under the impression that one of the key assumptions for the canonical ensemble was that all microstates were equally probable. It's this assumption that motivates the statistical argument of looking solely at the number of microstates corresponding to a given macrostate in order to find the corresponding probability of it arising. This argument yields the correct result of the Boltzman distribution which I would happily append to my original post if what I've said here is unclear.

Comment: No, canonical microstates are not equiprobable. At equilibrium, each microstate of energy $E_n$ has a probability proportional to $exp(-\beta E_n)$. Maybe you are confusing the probability distribution of the canonical ensemble with the microcanonical distribution of an enlarged system sometimes used to *derive* the canonical ensemble.

Comment: Wait you're right, I've looked at the canonical ensemble again and I'm getting probabilities that are functions of energy. But this result is obtained from the degeneracy of microstates in the reservoir, such that the joint states of microstates in the system and reservoir are all equally likely, indeed this is one of the assumptions in the derivation. So I think even here, the probabilities are all the same?

Comment: Okay I think I understand: so if we solely look at the system in the canonical ensemble and disregard the reservoir then the probabilities for the microstates of the system are not all equal as we fail to account for degeneracy in the reservoir. In this case, we can still define the entropy of the system using the Gibbs formula as we assert entropy be additive in such a way that adding the corresponding result for the reservoir will recover the equiprobable result I considered the first time around?